# pandas : how to groupby time and column

Tags: python

I have a list of sales products, and I would like to group the sales by product by month.
I am using a dataframe, which index is a time index, and have a column product.

I tried :

```
df.groupby(['product', pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1M')])['sales'].sum()
```

but it give an error :  'TimeGrouper' object is not callable

I also tried

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1M')).groupby('sales').sum()
```

but it gives an error : cannot access callable atttribute 'groupby' of 'dataframegroupby' objects.

Any ideas ?

PS : I can't copy paste code from my work to internet.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me. I'm not sure why you're getting the TypeError...

```
df.groupby(['product', pd.TimeGrouper('1M')])['sales'].sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed somewhere that a set_index on the date column solves the issue. So you could try

```
df.set_index(<DateTime Column>).groupby(['product', pd.TimeGrouper('1M')])['sales'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add another column to your DataFrame and use that for grouping:

```
df['month'] = [ts.month for ts in df.index]
df.groupby(['product', 'month'])['sales'].sum()
```